# Electrical noise sources in farms

Tags: sensor, analog, filter, noise, interference

I am designing the data logger of a solar-powered automatic weather station that will be installed in farms. It's used to gather data from environmental sensors (wired) and send it to a host using the cellular network.

One of these sensors is a Solar Radiation sensor. Its sensitivity is 15uV. I am designing the analog front end and already filtered the mains 50 Hz that may be present due to nearby power transmission towers.

**My question is:**

What are the other external noise sources that are present in a farm that may interfere with my system?

Comment: Radioactive chicken

Comment: Lightning can be a challenge.

Comment: Any electric/comm device, motor, etc... There is noise everywhere, you need to determine what is major issue and what is not. You should go take measurement to find out what are the main cause of noise.

Answer (score 2):

Electric fences are a nice wideband source of interference. Especially if there are bad contacts on the way (rusty connections, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Anything that can also be anywhere else.

Radio, TV, Radar, anything.

Post-RF-Radio any place on earth can have any amount of interference in the μV scale. It's why those designs need extra special attention, no matter where you put them. But be glad you're not designing for outside-of-earth, that's even more annoying.

And, of course, as Spehro says, lightning is always a fun thing with outside-electronics. Both being hit by and picking up induced spikes, the latter being even more likely, since "nearby strike" in that sense on a μV sensor can still be 100's of meters.

Answer (score 1):

In a farm, I would look for tractors or anything with engines and ignitions that can cause interference.

Comment: Diesel engines shouldn't cause any trouble though.

Comment: Injectors and fuel pumps are electrical.